# How to make a Non-Cumulative stacked bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, stacked-chart, stacked-bar-chart

If I have a data like this:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~x, ~yvalue, ~variable,
  "a", 1,  "red",
  "a", 2,  "blue",
  "b", 1,  "red",
  "b", 3,  "blue",
  "b", 0, "blue"
)
```

I want to make a chart like a stacked bar chart of values (not counts), but instead of the bars stacking cumulatively, I basically want, for each value of x ie a or b, a single bar showing for that value, which is made up of overlapping bars of different colors, one for each variable type red/blue.
When I use:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y, group = variable)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable))
```

I get a stacked count. So for eg, the first bar, where x = 'a', has a 1 unit high bar(red), then another 2 unit high bar on top (blue) bringing it up to 3. What I want is for this to show a 1 unit high bar(red), then another 1 unit high bar on top (blue) bringing the total height for to 2 for the blue bar.

Any help would be appreciated. I can't show you my expected output because unfortunately I can't get it to work!

Comment: Use `position = "dodge"`

Comment: I don't want each column side by side though. I want them overlapped into 1 column. I looked at position_dodge, but when you set the width to 0/0.01 or something low, the tallest bar shows up but the others are all 'behind it' so they become invisible,  and there's no way to adjust the ordering I can find, to bring everything to the front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual bars of a `geom_col` will be drawn in the order in which they appear in your data frame. You therefore need to arrange your data frame in descending order of `yvalue` and use `position = 'identity'` to get a non-stacking bar plot where all the bars are visible (unless you have two of the same height, in which case one will be invisible by definition)

```r
ggplot(data = df[order(-df$yvalue),], aes(x, yvalue)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = variable), position = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]